# solidity basic code setupment -Need help

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am beginner in solidity.I need these code with total setup.

1. Type: ERC20/BEP20
2. SUPPLY: FIXED
3. TOKEN NAME & SYMBOL: my token (MYT)
4. Total supply: 15B
5. Token distribution
   a. 5% Dev wallet (0xdwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
   b. 5% Marketing wallet (0xmwxxxxxxxx)
6. Decimal: 18
7. Fees: 3%
   1% buy fee: It will go to marketing Wallet as ETH
   2% sell fee: it will go to LP as ETH
8. Limit:
   a. Maximum buy Limit per transaction: 0.05%
   b. Maximum holding amount per wallet: 0.05%
9. Renounce ownership: No….
10. Liquidity: Auto generator token from sell fees
11. Trading pair: USDT USDC WBNB

Comment: Is this a free lance project?

Comment: Im trying to learn step by step....

Comment: Okay, that's great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a basic implementation of an ERC20 token with the specified requirements using Solidity and the OpenZeppelin library.

To set up your development environment:

- Install Node.js: Download and install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/.
- Install Hardhat: Open a terminal and run the following command to install Hardhat globally:

> npm install -g hardhat

- Create a new Hardhat project:

> mkdir my-token && cd my-token npx hardhat

- Install OpenZeppelin Contracts:

> npm install @openzeppelin/contracts

Now, you can create your custom token contract:
Create a new file named MyToken.sol in the contracts folder:

```
// contracts/MyToken.sol

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    address public marketingWallet;
    address public devWallet;

    constructor(address _marketingWallet, address _devWallet) ERC20("My Token", "MYT") {
        require(_marketingWallet != address(0) && _devWallet != address(0), "Invalid wallet addresses");

        marketingWallet = _marketingWallet;
        devWallet = _devWallet;

        uint256 totalSupply = 15 * 10**9 * 10**18; // 15 billion tokens with 18 decimals
        uint256 devTokens = (totalSupply * 5) / 100; // 5% for dev wallet
        uint256 marketingTokens = (totalSupply * 5) / 100; // 5% for marketing wallet

        _mint(devWallet, devTokens);
        _mint(marketingWallet, marketingTokens);
        _mint(msg.sender, totalSupply - devTokens - marketingTokens);
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal override {
        // Implement your custom fees and limits logic here

        super._transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}
```

This is a basic implementation of your token. You'll need to add the custom fees and limits logic in the _transfer function. You can also add the auto liquidity generation and trading pair features as needed.

- Compile the contract:

> npx hardhat compile

- Deploy the contract:
  Create a new file named deploy.js in the scripts folder:

// scripts/deploy.js

```
async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

    const MyToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken");
    const myToken = await MyToken.deploy("0xMarketingWalletAddress", "0xDevWalletAddress");

    console.log("MyToken address:", myToken.address);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Replace 0xMarketingWalletAddress and 0xDevWalletAddress with the actual wallet addresses.

- Add a local network to your hardhat.config.js:

  module.exports = {
  networks: {
  hardhat: {
  chainId: 1337,
  },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  };
- Run a local Hardhat node:

  npx hardhat node
- Deploy the contract to the local network:

  npx hardhat run --network hardhat scripts/deploy.js

This will give you a basic implementation of your token. You can further customize it by adding the required fees, limits, and other features as needed.

Comment: lots of thanks for reply , may I have your Telegram ID or email address....?

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer, would you mind to vote this answer? 
and my email address is svenwarrior29@gmail.com ,
telegram id: shinji_eth 
thanks